# Does scripture say that scripture should not be written down?

Tags: scripture

Shruti = "what is heard".  It is believed that the written scripture does not convey the essence.  Does a prohibition against writing scripture down exist in scripture?

Comment: There is no such prohibition. If there were such a prohibition, acharyas like Sri Shankara, Sri Ramanuja and Sri Madhva would never have written commentaries on scriptures.